# Laravel error: The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am trying to use the Put method and this is my result....

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.
http://localhost:3000/admin/genres/
```

This is the routing:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::redirect('/', 'records');
    Route::resource('genres', 'Admin\GenreController');
    Route::get('records', 'Admin\RecordController@index');
});
```

This is the function in the controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, Genres $genres)
    {
        // Validate $request
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|min:3|unique:genres,name,' . $genres->id
        ]);

        // Update genre
        $genres->name = $request->name;
        $genres->save();

        // Flash a success message to the session
        session()->flash('success', 'The genre has been updated');
        // Redirect to the master page
        return redirect('admin/genres');
    }
```

This is the HTML form code in blade:

```
@extends('layouts.template')

@section('title', 'Edit genre')

@section('main')
    <h1>Edit genre: {{ $genres->name }}</h1>
    <form action="/admin/genres/{{ $genres->id }}" method="post">
<!-- this is where is goes wrong i guess... -->
        @method('put')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"
                class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                placeholder="Name"
                minlength="3"
                required
                value="{{ old('name', $genres->name ?? '') }}">
            @error('name')
            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save genre</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

This is the routing table:

```
+--------+----------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method                                 | URI                       | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware |
+--------+----------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD                               | /                         |                  | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                                      | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS | admin                     |                  | Illuminate\Routing\RedirectController                                  | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | admin/genres              | genres.index     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\GenreController@index                       | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | POST                                   | admin/genres              | genres.store     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\GenreController@store                       | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | admin/genres/create       | genres.create    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\GenreController@create                      | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | admin/genres/{genre}      | genres.show      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\GenreController@show                        | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | PUT|PATCH                              | admin/genres/{genre}      | genres.update    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\GenreController@update                      | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | DELETE                                 | admin/genres/{genre}      | genres.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\GenreController@destroy                     | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | admin/genres/{genre}/edit | genres.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\GenreController@edit                        | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | admin/records             |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\RecordController@index                      | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | api/user                  |                  | Closure                                                                | api        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | contact-us                |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ContactUsController@show                          | web        |
|        | POST                                   | contact-us                |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ContactUsController@sendEmail                     | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | home                      | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | itunes                    |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ItunesController@index                            | web        |
|        | POST                                   | login                     |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | login                     | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | POST                                   | logout                    | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | password/confirm          | password.confirm | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST                                   | password/confirm          |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST                                   | password/email            | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | password/reset            | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web        |
|        | POST                                   | password/reset            | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | password/reset/{token}    | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | register                  | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | POST                                   | register                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | shop                      |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ShopController@index                              | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | shop/{id}                 |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ShopController@show                               | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS | user                      |                  | Illuminate\Routing\RedirectController                                  | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | user/password             |                  | App\Http\Controllers\User\PasswordController@edit                      | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST                                   | user/password             |                  | App\Http\Controllers\User\PasswordController@update                    | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | user/profile              |                  | App\Http\Controllers\User\ProfileController@edit                       | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST                                   | user/profile              |                  | App\Http\Controllers\User\ProfileController@update                     | web        |
|        |                                        |                           |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
+--------+----------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

I would really like some help since this is my school project :D my friends project works but we can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Excuse me for my bad english :D

Comment: your route specifies the 'get' method: `Route::get('records', 'Admin\RecordController@index');`. change that to `Route::put`

Comment: Thats for a different page the one thats being used ````Route::resource('genres', 'Admin\GenreController');```

Comment: Do `php artisan routes:list` to see what routes are defined with the resource

Comment: routing table is added :D

Comment: Your form action is `/admin/genres/{{ $genres->id }}` but the error message says you're hitting `/admin/genres/`. It looks like that `$genres->id` might be missing? View-source on your html form and see what that form action URL looks like.

Comment: Are you tried? `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: I have tried php artisan route:cache and its not an issue with the missing $genres->id my friend has the same code but it works

Comment: @IliasSmeulders but did you view-source and see what the generated form action URL is?

Comment: @jszobody we see a difference in the /admin/genres/ in the source indeed. 
I have /admin/genres/ and my friend has /admin/genres/1

Comment: @IliasSmeulders Then there's your issue. Figure out why `$genres->id` isn't giving you anything. That's your entire problem. This is not a routing issue.

Comment: @jszobody We are figuring it out... No luck so far. We are new in the language thanks for the help!! maybe if you find something tell us :D

Comment: @IliasSmeulders There's not enough information here to know what's happening. In the controller method that runs _before_ your form loads, try a `dd($genres)` to see what you have. Perhaps you haven't successfully loaded anything from the database? Regardless, that would need to be a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: I don't think it is your problem atm, but contrary to advice given here, you *don't* want to cache your routes in development. [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching): "*... you should only run the `route:cache` command during your project's deployment.*". For local development, caching routes makes no sense and will just cause confusing errors. If you've already run it, try `php artisan route:clear` to remove it and use your actual routes files.

Answer (score 0):

please try updating the action in the form like

```
<form action="{{ route('genres.update', ['genres' => $genres->id]) }}" method="POST">
@method('PUT')

// and in controller

public function update(Request $request, Genres $genres)
{
   dd($genres);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try with add `$id` in update action

like:

`public function update($id) { ....`

Comment: no, thats kinda weird maybe a little explanation?

Comment: like this : 

```
public function update(Request $request, Genres $genres, $id)
    {
        // Validate $request
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|min:3|unique:genres,name,' . $genres->id
        ]);

        // Update genre
        $genres->name = $request->name;
        $genres->save();

        // Flash a success message to the session
        session()->flash('success', 'The genre has been updated');
        // Redirect to the master page
        return redirect('admin/genres');
    }
```

Comment: $id is not recognized

Comment: This makes no sense - the error says there is no route for the request, so clearly the request is not reaching the `update()` method at all.